# tkinter doesnt open images

Tags: python, file, tkinter, background

please first look at the code :

```
from tkinter import*
import time 
import random 
class Game:
def __init__(self):
    self.tk = Tk()
    self.tk.title("Mr Stickman races for the exit")
    self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
    self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, highlightthickness= 0)
    self.canvas,Pack()
    self.tk.update()
    self.canvas_height = 500
    self.canvas_width = 500
    self.bg = PhotoImage(file="background1.gif")
    w = self.bg.width()
    h = self.bg.height()
    for x in range(0, 5):
        for y in range (0, 5):
            self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, Image= self.bg, anchor="nw")
    self.sprites = []
    self.running = True


def mainloop(self):
while 1:
    if self.running == True:
        for sprite in self.sprites:
            sprite.move()
    self.tk.update_idletasks()
    self.tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

g = Game()
g.mainloop()
```

when i run it, it shows this:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "background1.gif": no such file or directory
```

I tried also in this way and got this error:

```
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Sajjad\\Documents\\python")
```

i put the files excat location but got this:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Sajjad\Documents\python": permission denied
```

what should i do ?

Comment: You must give it a valid path to a file. If you don't give a full path, the file is assumed to be in the current working directory, which might not be the same as the directory where your script is.

Comment: that is most certainly not the exact file location, exact file location also has to include filename and extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider multiple things:

1- Select and find the image address correctly - in my case, I placed image and script in same folder

```py
file=sys.path[0] + "/imageName.imageExt"
```

2- Replace

```py
Image=self.bg
```

with

```py
image=self.bg
```

3- Use place, pack or grid to put your canvas in application window; like this:

```py
self.canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
```

or better in your case:

```py
self.canvas.pack()
```

4- Pay attension to indented blocks

Source:

```py
from tkinter import*
import time
import sys


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Mr Stickman races for the exit")
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500,
                             height=500, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas, Pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500

        # ***CHANGE "/back.png" WITH YOUR IMAGE; THIS IS JUST FOR TEST***
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file=sys.path[0] + "/back.png")  # HERE sys.path
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(
                    x * w, y * h, image=self.bg, anchor="nw")  # HERE Image -> image
                self.canvas.pack()  # HERE
        self.sprites = []
        self.running = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)


g = Game()
g.mainloop()
```

This is the "back.png" image that I painted in a graphical software:

[image]

Final output:

[image]